# Query regarding boarding point in Indian railways

Tags: trains, indian-railways, train-stations

I have booked ticket from Secunderabad to Chennai.
But now due to changes in mu shedule I want board train at Khammam station.

Can I board that train and claim my berth on my same ticket?
Train name: CHARMINAR EXPRESS
Class: 3 tire ac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can board the train at Khammam station.

Comment: Can you please supply a link to an official website that support your answer?

Comment: Please provide me with correct information as I am new to this type of journies